# Problem installing ubuntu newer than 16.04.4 LTS

Tags: system-installation

How do you do?
So as the title states whenever I try to install from scratch newer versions of Ubuntu it just hangs in the wallpaper before you select language and etc.
Here's a pic I took from the display as printscreen was not available.
[PrintScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqJIo.jpg)

Any ideas? My desktop is an AMD FX8530, mobo Asus Sabretooth 990FX rev1, VGA Radeon R7 350 and 16gb of ram. What I think it's weird is because 16.04.4 installs smoothly and newer than this hangs at the printscreen I took.
Any help will be more than appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: Try booting the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and enable the **nomodeset** option. This will eliminate a problem with the graphic card.

Comment: @heynnema thanks for your response! Problem is if I go to live version it hangs at the very same place and not enabling me to set that option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When booting the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, watch carefully, and on one of the very early screens, you'll see a little man icon at the bottom/center of the screen.

I forget which...

Either:

- click the little man icon
- hit the down arrow key when you see the little man icon
- hold down the shift key before/during the little man icon

Once you see the boot options, enable the **nomodeset** option, and try to continue booting.

Comment: It actually worked! I can get into the system live cd. Do I have to do anything else if I install from here to get my graphic card working properly? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just go ahead and install, and it'll probably work fine. You may have to install Nvidia drivers if you have such a video card. BTW... which one of the 3 options worked for you?